# how to convert json date to c# in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to convert the json date to c# datetime format

> date is  3190549620000
>
> and it orginal date format is 24jan2014 1:17pm

how can i convert this , meanwhile i followed this [blog](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735917.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20flipcart%20like%20panel%20for%20showing%20products%20in%20gridview) but it not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `3190549620000` is very big, causing an overflow when using the method you linked to. 
`3190549620` (divided by 1000, meaning the original is in *milli* seconds ) works better.

Secondly, if I use the method you link to to revert to a unix timestamp, I get 1390565820.

Compare

`1390565820`
`3190549620`

If I reverse the 31 in your example to 13, I get the correct date, but incorrect time. Can you verify and confirm that your input starts with 31 and not 13?

The date issue is a simple one: it seems to be 5:30 difference. What timezone are you in? My guess would be IST, so that is simply a timezone offset issue :)

It seems that your timestamp () is in UTC.

Change the code from your link to:

```
 private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
 {
     var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
     return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp / 1000).ToLocalTime();
 }
```

If I use `1390549620000` instead of your `3190549620000` as input, I get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what is represented by that integer. Normally in a lot of services EPOCH dates are used. These EPOCH number are seconds since 1/1/1970 0:0:0, the first date in Unix. But maybe the service you are consuming is returning you ticks, or another format of date. Can you take a look at the docs??